# Miller-Rabin Primality Test-Witnesses and Liars - Implementing in Python

Tags: cryptography, python, primality-test

I have been studying the Miller-Rabin Primality Test, and am interested in implementing a code in Python to count witnesses and liars. In the basic code to determine if a number is probably prime or composite, I would like to incorporate 1) and 2) below to better understand witnesses compared to liars for n values:

$1)$ $a$ to be tested for all values of $a$ from $1<a<n-1$, not random as it is currently coded.

$2)$ Then for every $a$ in $1)$ above, a count of how many of those $a's$ are witnesses and how many are non-witnesses(liars)

My ultimate goal is to use this, I'm sure with more modifications to the code, to compare to the Theorem: If n is odd, composite, and n>9, then at least 75% of the elements in $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^x$ are Miller-Rabin witnesses.

The Python code I am using is as follows:

```
from random import randrange

def probably_prime(n, k):
"""Return True if n passes k rounds of the Miller-Rabin primality
test (and is probably prime). Return False if n is proved to be
composite.

"""
if n < 2: return False

r, m = 0, n - 1
while m % 2 == 0:
    r += 1
    m //= 2
for _ in range(k):
    a = randrange(2, n - 1)
    x = pow(a, m, n)
    if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
        continue
    for _ in range(r - 1):
        x = pow(x, 2, n)
        if x == n - 1:
            break
    else:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: I am not sure I get your questions. For question 1, do you mean you want to add $\alpha$ as an argument in your algorithm? For question 2, do you mean you want to test every single $\alpha$ from 1 to $n-1$, and find which are Miller-Rabin liars and which are not?

Comment: For 1) I would like to test every $a$ in the range, not random as it is now. 2) Yes, that is correct - Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just run over all $a$ with a `for` loop, like the one you already use for `_`? Before the loop on $a$ starts, you can define two variables both set to 0, which you increment later on as needed to count the witnesses & liars.

Comment: Thank you, I will work on this, but I am very new to coding and do not have a great understanding of it at this point...but I am really trying :)

Comment: Question has been edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) You can change the code to:

```
def probably_prime(n, k, a):
"""Return True if n passes k rounds of the Miller-Rabin primality
test (and is probably prime). Return False if n is proved to be
composite.

"""
if n < 2: return False

r, m = 0, n - 1
while m % 2 == 0:
    r += 1
    m //= 2
for _ in range(k):
    #a = randrange(2, n - 1)
    x = pow(a, m, n)
    if x == 1 or x == n - 1:
        continue
    for _ in range(r - 1):
        x = pow(x, 2, n)
        if x == n - 1:
            break
    else:
        return False
return True
```

and then fix some number n, and some k, which is the number of repetitions. Then add at the end:

```
Result=[]
For a in range(1,n):
    Result.append(probably_prime(n,k,a))
```

Result is a list with all outcomes for $a$ in the required range. True means composite (ie witness), and false means liar.
To find which $a$'s are liars and which are witnesses you can then add:

```
witnesses=sum(Result)
liars=n-witnesses
```

Comment: Thank you. I will be working on this in the next few hours. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Alexandros-I have been trying to get Python code to work, but have not succeeded. When you indicated to fix some number n and k, I am doing as probably_prime(n, k), but you now have probably_prime(n, k, a) so it wants a value for a. How should I be fixing n and k, and isn't a just running through all from 1<a<n-1? Then you have the part to add at the end: Result=[]....I attempted this part after fixing n and k but it did not work, probably because I am not entering the n and k correctly.  I you don't mind can you let me know where you think I could be going wrong from what I have indicated.

Comment: When I said fix n,k i meant to choose a number n which you wish to test whether it is prime or not, and choose a number k as the number of trials. Ie if you wish to test whether n=500 is prime with 5 repetitions,  you should add these two lines at the beginning of your code: n=500, k=5. Also, probably_prime(n,k) is not going to work anymore, you need to use probably_prime(n,k,a).

Comment: Sorry I got confused as when you indicated to fix n and k you mentioned it after the main part of the code, and that is when I normally enter the definition with the values.  So I will now fix at the beginning (by just entering two lines of code n=value,k=value) and add the last two blocks, Result=.. and Witnesses=... at the end of the main part of the code. Thank you again, and I hope you do not mind so many questions :)

Comment: Alexandros - I still don't have code working.  I define n and k at the beginning, then entered the main body of the code, then the last two blocks of code, Lastly, I call it by the definition and it returns "...name a is not defined" Any ideas? I have tried a variety of ways, but just cannot get it working. Maybe it is something simple I am just not aware of.

Comment: literally do not understand what your problem is.  https://i.imgur.com/Gg2PSKq.png

Comment: Alexandros, thank you again. I got it to work as you did! The problem was due to the spacing on the last two blocks as well as me not including print(witnesses,liars). May I ask one last question...How do I also get it to print True or False to Composite or Probably Prime for that value of n? I know the print(Result) will give me all the outcomes for each "a", but can I also do an option as a final conclusion for that value of "n".

Comment: Idea:  if liars>witnesses then print "Probably Prime" and                                                           
          if witnesses>liars: print "Composite"............but not sure on coding

Comment: Alexandros - I have everything working as I had hoped :) I will be modifying as I work with Miller-Rabin some more, and know more of what I need. I appreciate your help and patience :)

Comment: @Locally unskillful: <br/>1. your code repeats the Miller-Rabin test k times with the same base<br/>2. True means "probably prime", i.e. $a$ may be a liar and False means "composite", in that case $a$ is a (true) witness<br/>3. sum(witnesses) counts the liars

Answer (score 0):

A simple code that returns a list of liars or 'None' if n is prime is:

```
# Miller-Rabin-Test of n, base a
def miller_rabin(n, a):
    d = n1 = n-1
    s = 0
    while d & 1 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        s += 1
    b = pow(a, d, n)
    if b == 1 or b == n1: return True
    while s > 1:
        s -= 1
        b = (b*b) % n
        if b == n1: return True 
    return False

# perform Miller-Rabin-Test of n with bases 1 < a < n-1 and return a list of strong liars (false witnesses) or 'None' if n is prime
def get_liars(n):
    result = []
    passed = 0
    for a in range(2, n-1):
        if miller_rabin(n, a):
            passed += 1
            if passed > n//4:
                return None    # n is prime
            result += [a]
    return result

# main program for testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        n = int(input("n = "))
        if n == 0: break
        if n < 3: continue
        liars = get_liars(n)
        if liars is None:
            print (n, "is prime")
        else:
            print (n, f"is composite, {len(liars)} liars:", liars)
```

The output for $n = 65$ would be

65 is composite, 4 liars: [8, 18, 47, 57]

The function *get_liars* returns *None* if the test has been passed with more than $n/4$ bases because $n$ is certainly a prime then.